# JS convert 32bit png image to 24bit

Tags: javascript

I have a canvas from which I get a png image for printing, it is always 32bit. Due to the fact that the printer prints monochrome 24bit images, I need to convert the image from 32bit to 24bit. How can this be done using javascript?

```
  const canv = document.createElement('canvas');
  const c = canv.getContext('2d');
  c.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That sort of conversion should occur in the printer-handling code of your browser, you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: @AKX I don’t know why, but only 24bit images are printed on my printer without any problems. The rest are either not printed or blurry :(